# Rescuing an iTouch 5 from iOS Update

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, software-update

I did something mildly dumb and decided I'd finally try updating my old iPod Touch 5 to the latest version of iOS (9.3.5) from the iOS 7.1.2.

Unfortunately, while it meant that some of my apps worked better, it also introduced a good 10s input lag whenever I wanted to unlock the screen or change songs more than once. I tried using a backup from before the update, but for some reason it kept the iOS version at 9.3.5, so I tried downloading 8.4.1 and updating from that .ipsw file.

The update failed with an error 3194 (presumably, 8.4.1 has exited the "signing window" I saw mentioned when I was downloading the .ipsw and thus won't update properly), and now my iPod Touch is locked into recovery mode.

Is there a solution to circumvent the update verification, or otherwise restore my iPod to its former, functional state? Or am I doomed to either an unconscionable amount of lag or buying a more recent iPod?